# How to retrieve receipt_url upon successful payment completion in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

We are using the Stripe API to make payments for invoices using a SAPUI5/Fiori UI. The payment intent create happens via a node.js project. We are successfully able to initiate the payment and from the Stripe dashboard Payments section we can see that the payment gets processed successfully.

We have the requirement, that upon successful payment completion, we need to redirect the user to the receipt URL (receipt_url) to display the payment receipt of the just processed invoice. Below is the code we are using to invoke the create payment intent on the Stripe server:

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
    {
    payment_method_types: ['card', 'us_bank_account'],
    metadata: {
        ....
        ....
        ....
    },
  },
    {apiKey: secretKey}
);
res.send({
  clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
});
```

According to the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/retrieve), we can retrieve the receipt URL by retrieving the charge within the paymentIntent, but the response we receive upon successful processing of the payment by Stripe does not contain the charge object, it just has the payment id. Is it possible in any way, to retrieve the receipt URL using only the payment intent id?

Calling the payment intent create on Stripe to process the payment, but we are not getting in the response the receipt_url value where we want to redirect the user to, upon successful payment completion.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `receipt_url` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-receipt_email) on the `latest_charge` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-latest_charge) (make sure you use an API version greater than `2022-11-15`; in older versions, it was the last item of  `charges` property), which you can [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) on your successful Payment Intent.

For that, you need to add a parameter `expand` when you create a Payment Intent:

```js
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    …
    expand: [“latest_charge”]
});

const receiptUrl = paymentIntent.latest_charge.receipt_url;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Vanya, and apologies for the late post.

I tried expanding the charges property as below, still I don't see the same being returned in the response post successful payment (status=succeeded):


const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    …
    expand: [“charges”]
});

const receiptUrl = paymentIntent.charges.receipt_url;

Comment: `paymentIntent.charges` is an array in API versions older than 2022-11-15, you can try `paymentIntent.charges[0].receipt_url`.

Comment: I am actually using API version 2022-08-01. And when Stripe is sending back the response upon successful payment, we can't see any charges object within the paymentIntent object. We are using API Key in test mode on Stripe - could this be the reason why Stripe does not send the charges object in the response, since the payment source isn't actually charged anything in test mode API key?